# Magento adminhtml AJAX query returns 302 status

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am currently developing a Magento extension whose main components are a frontend widget and a backend admin options panel. I have no frontend controller, but I have an `adminhtml` controller that is giving me some trouble. Here is some of the code in my controller.

File: /app/code/community/Mynamespace/Myextension/controllers/Adminhtml/MybackendController.php

```
class Mynamespace_Myextension_Adminhtml_MybackendController
    extends Mage_adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    protected function normalAction() {
    }

    protected function ajaxAction() {
        die('got here');
    }
}
```

`normalAction` is an action that is called by navigating through links such as `http://mystore.com/index.php/admin/mybackend/normal/key/.../` . There are a few actions like this such as `index`, `save`, `edit`, `grid`, etc. The entry point to my controller is a menu entry that leads to the `index` action. All such actions work as expected.

`ajaxAction` is an action that is called only through an AJAX POST query.

*The problem is that whenever I attempt to do this, I get a 302 HTTP status code reply that redirects to the admin dashboard* (`admin/index/index`). If I try to access this action directly by typing its link in the browser, I still get a 302. If I add a menu entry to this action, then it works as expected and I see the "got here" text.

The Javascript/jQuery code that does the AJAX request is not complex:

```
$.post(
    'http://mystore.com/index.php/admin/mybackend/ajax/key/.../',
    somePostDataObject,
    function() {
        alert( 'success' );
    }
);
```

Note that the success function gets called even though the status code is 302.

I tried debugging the routing mechanism to understand exactly what causes it to redirect. So far I have deduced that a problem occurs in the `preDispatch` method of the `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` class. The module, controller and action are successfully resolved and the request is marked as dispatched (`_dispatched` property is true) until the `controller_action_predispatch` event is dispatched. After the event is resolved, the request appears as not being dispatched (`_dispatched` becomes false). Presumably one of the objects that listen for this event does some further processing on the request and rejects it. I have not been able to debug any deeper than this.

Normally I would post some code to help you understand what's going on even better, but there are quite a lot of lines to copy from the various configuration files and classes, so I will do that as people write comments or answers asking to see specific files. So far, I believe the configuration is correct, as all the other functionality besides the AJAX request is working ok.

Comment: should you be using HTTPS?

Comment: I am not using HTTPS at all (neither on the frontend nor on the backend).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Url should be `http://mystore.com/index.php/admin/mybackend/ajax/key/.../?isAjax=true`, so magento knows this is an ajax request.

Also you need to provide a from_key in your POST data which is stored in the global JavaScript Variable `window.FORM_KEY`.

Your jQuery Request should look something like this:

```
function magentoAdminAjax(data, callback) {
    data.form_key = window.FORM_KEY;
    $.post(
        'http://mystore.com/index.php/admin/mybackend/ajax/key/.../?isAjax=true',
        data,
        callback
    );
}
```

The Code for this check can be found in Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::preDispatch(Line: 164) (magento-1.7.0.2)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I apologize for taking such a long time to accept it - I had to work on another project in the meantime. I was missing `isAjax=true` in my requests. This is why it wasn't working. However, instead of adding the parameter to the jQuery request, I decided to go with the Prototype-style requests that Magento normally uses: `Ajax.Request` . It automatically adds `isAjax` as well. It might seem wrong to mix jQuery and Prototype, but I need Prototype anyway to interface with the various Magento widgets (grids, image choosers, etc.) so in the end it all works out :)

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue I had as well. Apparently you can make ajax GET requests without the form key, but as soon as you use POST it starts redirecting to the dashboard without it.